# Perl newline replace

Tags: perl, newline

Using the example below, I'm trying to replace "\n\nbeer/name: " with a "|" character:

```
beer/name: The Horseman's Ale
beer/beerId: 33061
beer/brewerId: 14359
beer/ABV: 5.20

beer/name: blah beer
beer/beerId: 33045
beer/brewerId: 14678
beer/ABV: 5.98

...
```

I am using the following to attempt to do this, but it is deleting the whole file.

```
perl -pi -0 -w -e "s,\nbeer/name,|,g" file.txt
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Substitution loop at -e line 1, <> chunk 1.
```

How can I modify this code  to work?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. On my system the file is *not* deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I should have said "all of the content in the file is deleted". The actual file remains, it just has no content.

Comment: I must give you the same answer though. On my system the empty line and `beer/name` is replaced by a `|` and the remaining file contents stay intact.

Comment: Thanks Olaf - That's good to know. Maybe there is something else wrong on my machine. The only response I'm getting from the terminal is "Substitution loop at -e line 1, <> chunk 1." Does that tell me anything?

Comment: I would guess, the example text and/or the `s///` in your question isn't exactly as you really use it on your machine.

Comment: Please, always include any error messages in your question. Yours is listed in [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Subroutine-%25s-redefined): "(P: An internal error you should never see) The substitution was looping infinitely. (Obviously, a substitution shouldn't iterate more times than there are characters of input, which is what happened.) See the discussion of substitution in [Regexp Quote-Like Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)." --- Are you on Windows?

Comment: Sorry nandhp, will do next time. I'm on a mac.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. Olaf - you were right. There is something weird going on with my file. When I take a small extract of the file, this script works. It is only when I have the complete file, with millions of records, that I get this problem. Thanks again!

Comment: 1) The switch `-0` will enable slurp mode with your file, reading the entire file into one line, which is not a very nice thing to do if your input file contains millions of records. Paragraph mode `-00` might be better suited.

Comment: 2) The error `Name "main::beer" used only once` suggests that what you actually had in your regex was `$beer`, which is to say a variable. A logical consequence of this is that `$beer` would have been undefined (since you did not intentionally use it), which means that since you had warnings on (a good idea) you would also have seen `Use of uninitialized value $beer in regexp compilation`. Unless, of course, you did `no warnings 'uninitialized'`, which of course is absurd, because surely you would have said so. But still, there it is. Your information does not add up.

Comment: TLP - your right. The error was: "Substitution loop at -e line 1, <> chunk 1." I think the problem is my file is too big. the problem with using -00 is that because it reads line-by-line, it cannot see a newline AND text on the next line. In other words, because I'm searching for a string across multiple lines, I cannot analyze the file one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to rightly understand your need, but

I tested this in this way:

```
perl -0pwe "s,\nbeer/name,|,g" <<<"beer/name: The Horseman's Ale"$'\nbeer/beerId: 33061\nbeer/brewerId: 14359\nbeer/ABV: 5.20\n\nbeer/name: blah beer\nbeer/beerId: 33045\nbeer/brewerId: 14678'
```

on command line.

The output:

```
beer/name: The Horseman's Ale
beer/beerId: 33061
beer/brewerId: 14359
beer/ABV: 5.20
|: blah beer
beer/beerId: 33045
beer/brewerId: 14678
```

Replacing the perl part by `cat` ensure the test flow:

```
cat <<<"beer/name: The Horseman's Ale"$'\nbeer/beerId: 33061\nbeer/brewerId: 14359\nbeer/ABV: 5.20\n\nbeer/name: blah beer\nbeer/beerId: 33045\nbeer/brewerId: 14678' | sed 's/^/    /'
```

output:

```
beer/name: The Horseman's Ale
beer/beerId: 33061
beer/brewerId: 14359
beer/ABV: 5.20

beer/name: blah beer
beer/beerId: 33045
beer/brewerId: 14678
```

So from there I could easely hit <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and use <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> to reach position to modify you line...

Once you're output match your need, you could simple replace your switchs:

```
perl -0pwe '...' -i.bak path/filename
```

Or build a perl script:

```
perltidy <<< 's,\nbeer/name,|,g'

sed '1i#!/usr/local/bin/perl -0pwi.bak\nuse strict;' <(
    perltidy <<< 's,\nbeer/name,|,g') >myscript.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but helps in preserving the working file.

To prevent the file from being "deleted/cleared", you can add a backup suffix to the `-i` switch. This saves the original file with the given extension.

From [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*%5b_extension_%5d)

> **-i[extension]**
>
> specifies that files processed by the <> construct are to be edited in-place. It does this by renaming the input file, opening the output file by the original name, and selecting that output file as the default for print() statements. The extension, if supplied, is used to modify the name of the old file to make a backup copy, following these rules:
> ...